# Javascript add/subtract issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to javascript but I need a JS way to increment/decrement a value in my input field upon button click. I have my value set to show 0 successfully but when I click the add button it doesn't increase.

Here is the code in html and JS:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0'   />
<button id="add" class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success"  style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
```

Javascript:

```
@section('loadjs')
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/pagination.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/bower_components/uikit/js/components/slider.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/factory.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script
$("#add").click(function(){
var value = $("#value").val();
value = +value + 10;
$("#value").val(value);
});
></script>
@endsection
```

What am I missing in the JS side?

Comment: where have you initialized `value `??

Comment: Oh i have value in my input but I didn't initialize it there. Would that have to be an id on input? Or initialized in JS?

Comment: You want to increment it by 10 everytime??

Comment: yes for testing. I'll modify it as I need to though

Comment: You could just use the input type `number` with the attribute `step` set to 10

Comment: Do you have an element with an id of value?

Comment: @TomN. check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the value of input and then increase or decrease the value. And when you store the value in variable and wants to perform add operation on it you need to add `+` sign before variable and `input` elements don't have `text` property you need to use `value` to set it like this

```js
$("#add").click(function(){
var value = $("#value").val();
value = +value + 10;
$("#value").val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="md-input" id="value" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0'   />
<button id="add" class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success"  style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
```

Comment: This looks perfect. I've added and still nothing but I'm wondering, do I need to load a certain JS Script? I have it in my laravel blade in my @section('loadjs')

Comment: @TomN. you need to add jquery `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Hmm I added my JS section above, still no luck. I'll have to keep trying

Comment: None that I see, and the console shows it loading the jquery file

Comment: can you console.log(value) and see what's printing. Also check if click event is triggering or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158355/discussion-between-sanchit-patiyal-and-tom-n).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code and it would help to create a fiddle. But for now lets look at what you have:

```
$("#add").click(function(){

// Here you count up value but don't tell your code what value is?
// so add my line below
value = $("#value").val();
// I've force value back to a number by *1 
value = (value*1) + 10;
// Then your code resets the value to the new value
$("#value").text(value);
});
```

Depending on your use scenario you can also use a caching mechanism as follows:

```
  // I create the value var outside my event handler
   var value = $("#value").val();
   // Or if i know that it will always start on zero
   var value = 0 

   $("#add").click(function(){

    // here the addition of 10 will compound and be remembered
    // since the value var is outside my event handler,  
    value = value + 10;
    // Then your code resets the value to the new value
    $("#value").text(value);
    });
```

Comment: I should have clarified, the input field in my code above is currently set to a value of '0'. This is what I would like to increase and show the number in

Comment: I have updated my code if you see the second solution i start value at zero outside the scope of the event click, i then increment it by 10.

Comment: @tomN I have updated my code it should be clear and solves the issue can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize `value`:

```
var value = 0;
$("#add").click(function(){
value = value + 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var value = $("#value").val() + 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dtar43jp/

You're manipulating a variable called "value" in your click handler, which I'm guessing you might be intending to correspond to the DOM Element's value property.  However, if you're not assigning to Element.value directly, that will have no effect.

Since you appear to be using jQuery, the solution is to use `.val()`, which will return the value (as a string) when called with no parameters, and will set the value of the Element if passed a parameter (e.g. `.val(10)` sets the Element.value to 10).

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the current value and sum 10.

When you get an element's value you'll get it as a `String`, so you have to parse it to an `Integer` to prevent exceptions.

As you can see the `+` operator (placed before the `$()`) works as a parser as well (JS trick).

**Add value:**

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#value").text((+$('#value').val()) + 10);
});
```

**Subtract value:**

```
$("#sub").click(function(){
    $("#value").text((+$('#value').val()) - 10);
});
```